# Как исключать "ненужные" файлы из пакетов, установленных через composer?

Tags: php, composer, bower

Так как composer не позволяет создать точный список файлов, которые нужно загрузить из того или иного пакета/репозитория, не могу определиться, как же все таки в production отправлять легковесный продукт, без сотен и даже тысяч неиспользуемых файлов.

Мы используем fxp/composer-asset-plugin, для установки bower пакетов через composer, и проблему в основном доставляют именно JS пакеты. Т.е. нам нужен 1 файл, а подгружается весь проект с сотнями файлов. Простой пример: нам нужен только bootstrap.min.js, но мы не можем только его получить через composer.

Есть 3 мысли:

1. Написать скрипт, который будет удалять лишние файлы, во время вызова composer'ных хуков. "post-install", "post-update". Или воспользоваться плагином: https://github.com/octolab/Cleaner/wiki ?
2. Не очень красивый. Загрузить с помощью composer'а пакет, вручную удалить все лишнее и исключить его из composer.json, чтобы не обновлялся. По сути просто положить стороннюю библиотеку в её логичное место - папку "vendors", но отключить по сути от composer'а.
3. Наверняка кто-то скажет, что нужно чистить проект только в момент сборки production версии, но нам это не подходит, так как нам и в разработке не нужно огромное множество неиспользуемых файлов, так как они замусоривают, замедляют IDE, усложняют повседневную работу и так с большим проектом.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вы решали данную проблему?

Comment: Я думаю в этом случае, также как и в проектах, сделанных на c++, используется CMake файл, вам придётся писать скрипт для деплоймента. Я откопал PHPшнурую программу для вас - https://deployer.org

Answer (score 0):

Напишите скрипт, который будет копировать необходимые вам файлы в специальную папку, а все «тяжёлые» пакеты перенесите в `require-dev`.

Такой скрипт удобно сразу встроить в раздел `scripts` композера — тогда для создания production-версии достаточно будет только запустить лишний раз композер (так, чтобы сработал нужный скрипт).